# Pdf of product of two i.i.d random variable distributed as circular symmetric gaussian

Tags: gaussian, mimo, complex-random-variable

What is a distribution of the product of two circular symmetric Gaussian random variables?
i.e $X ~ CN(0,1)$ and $Y ~ CN(0,1)$ then distribution of $XY.$?

Comment: How is this related to signal processing? Would a math or statistics related SE be a better place for this question?

Comment: How do you define the product of $(X,Y)$ and $(W,Z)$? $(XW, YZ))$? $(XW-YZ) = \Re((X+jY)(W+jZ)^*)$? $(XW+YZ)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I meant following: X ~ CN(0,1), Y ~ CN(0,1), then distribution of XY?

Comment: @MBaz this is related to MIMO signal processing so i thought of putting this is signal processing

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Independent_complex-valued_central-normal_distributions) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_of_the_product_of_two_random_variables#Independent_complex-valued_noncentral_normal_distributions).